# GetFields returning empty array

Tags: c#, reflection

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong below? The type has the public property that the service method is trying to access so why is it not being picked up by reflection?

```
Public class SomeClass
{
   private YetAnotherClass yetAnotherClass;

   public SomeClass(SomeOtherClass otherclass)
   {
       this.yetAnotherClass = otherclass.SomeProperty;
   }

   public YetAnotherClass SomeProperty
   {
       get { return this.yetAnotherClass; }
   }
}

Public class ServiceClass
{
    public void DoSomething(SomeClass someclass)
    {
         Type type = someclass.GetType();
         FieldInfo[] fieldsinfo = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance); // returns empty collection
         FieldInfo fieldinfo = type.GetField("SomeProperty"); // returns null reference exception
    }
}
```

Cheers

Stewart

Answer (score 14):

SomeProperty is - as the name says - a property. Use `GetProperty` and `GetProperties` instead! That leads to `PropertyInfo` instead of `FieldInfo`.

Comment: Thanks so much. I wasted for an hour trying to figure this out.